# How to make that a background-image knows its height in CSS?

Tags: html, image, css

I'm working on a website and want to enter my title in a background-image because it has a special font. In school we learned it has to be this way. How can I make that I don't need to give a height to my background-image and it just pops up with the correct size? Thx!

```css
.title{
  background-image: url(...);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*it displays nothing now, only when I add a height here*/
}

.titlespan{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title"><span class="spantitle"></span></h1>
```

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to be that way - you can use an `img` tag, or render it with SVG, or any other number of ways. As you're well aware, backgrounds are not true content and do not inform element dimensions, which is why you need to specify height.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.title{
  background-image: url(...);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center; /* bonus, to position the background image */
}
```

'background-size:contain' will ensure that both the height and width of the background image fit inside an element.